# Set configuration with Liquibase

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

Is there a way to set configuration values, like

```
SET postgis.enable_outdb_rasters TO True;
SET postgis.enable_outdb_rasters = default;
SET postgis.enable_outdb_rasters = True;
SET postgis.enable_outdb_rasters = False;
```

as taken from [PostGIS' documentation](https://postgis.net/docs/postgis_gdal_enabled_drivers.html), in Liquibase? I think I could write a script that performs the mentioned SQL statement, but I was wondering if there's a "Liquibase way" for it too!

Comment: You need to put those statements in a `<sql>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by a_horse_with_no_name, you need an [`<sql>` tag](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql.html) to insert a statement like this to a liquibase changeset. It might be a good idea to restrict this to PostgreSQL explicitly by adding the attribute `dbms=postgresql` to the `<changeset>` or `<sql>` tag.

The statements you show will change the setting only for the current session.

If you want them to stick for future connections for everybody, you could use `ALTER SYSTEM`:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET postgis.enable_outdb_rasters = on;
```

Or you can change the user or the database so that the parameter is always set when you connect:

```
ALTER DATABASE mydatabase SET postgis.enable_outdb_rasters = on;
```

or

```
ALTER ROLE myuser SET postgis.enable_outdb_rasters = on;
```